# Unable to get run js from command to query mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am trying to run a simple JavaScript program to retrieve data from mongodb. collection named **news**.

```
var doc=db.news.findone();
printjson(doc);
```

I have mongodb running in my machine. when I try to run it from my command prompt, I am getting the below result.

> ```
> MongoDB shell version:2.4.15-pre-
> connecting to: test
> ```

I have no idea why it is connecting to test. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the collection, "news" resides on some mongo logical database, which need to be specified in script. For exmaple

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('db_name')
doc = db.news.findOne()
printjson(doc)
```

Then evaluate the script using

```
mongo --host ${host} --port ${port} script.js
```

If you don't specify a database in your connection string like for example,

```
//Connect to foo
${host}:${port}/foo
```

mongo will always try to connect to "test" database.